# Why is my AJAX request not returning the correct text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a HTML file and a PHP file.

The HTML file has 3 clickable div buttons. When I click each of them, they should trigger a different Javascript function that returns different AJAX response.

My problem is that no matter which button I click, the program always produces the same AJAX response from only one function.

Specifically, no matter which button I click, the program always sends out a GET request from the showAll() function. I know this because I make the PHP file print out the GET request parameter and it always says the "show" parameter equals to "all", when I want the parameter to equal to "major" or "course".

HTML

```
<div id="List">
      <div id="entries">
  </div>

  <a href="" onclick="showAll()">
      <div id="button_all" class="buttons">
          <p> Show All</p>
      </div>
  </a>

    <input id="major" type="text">

  <a href="" onclick="filterM()">
        <div class="buttons">
            <p>Filter by Major</p>
        </div>
  </a>

      <input id="course" type="text">

  <a href="" onclick="filterC()">
    <div class="buttons">
            <p>Filter by Course</p>
        </div>
  </a>

</div>

<script>

  function showAll(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var mesgs = document.getElementById("entries");
        mesgs.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("button_all").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","queryEntries.php?show=all", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

  function filterM() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var majorName = document.getElementById("major").value;
    alert("filterM() has been clicked and majorName is " + majorName);
    if(window.XMLHttprequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var mesgs = document.getElementById("entries");
        mesgs.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("button_all").style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "queryEntries.php?show=major&value=" + majorName, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

function filterC() {
  alert("filterC() had been clicked");
  var xmlhttp;
  var courseName = document.getElementById("course");
  if(window.XMLHttprequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      var mesgs = document.getElementById("entries");
      mesgs.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "queryEntries.php?show=course&value=" + courseName, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  document.getElementById("button_all").style.display = "block";
}

    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$db_server = "...";
$db_user = "...";
$db_pwd = "...";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die('Connection failed! ' . mysqli_error($conn));

// Select database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "h3517511") or die("Selection failed! " . mysqli_error($conn));

// Construct SQL query
echo "The show is: " . $_GET['show'] . "<br>";
echo "The value is: " . $_GET['value'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM attendanceList';

if ($_GET['show'] == "major") {
    echo "MAJOR";
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM attendanceList WHERE major = "'.$_GET['value'].'" ';
}

if ($_GET['show'] == "course") {
    echo "COURSE";
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM attendanceList WHERE course = '.$_GET['value'].' ';
}

// Execute SQL query
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Query execution failed! ' . mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    print "<div id=".$row['id'].">";
    print "<span>".$row['attendOrNot']."</span>";
    print "<h3>".$row['studentname']." (".$row['major'].")</h3>";
    print "<h5>(".$row['course'].") on ".$row['coursedate']." </h5>";
    print "</div>";
}

    ?>
```

Comment: put a '#' into the href. You are actually 'submitting' the href (as a link to the current script): `<a href="#" onclick="showAll()">`

Comment: As said by @Andreas, be careful to SQL injection. Please think about prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it's based on yours but uses only one JS function with variables, which is easy to control and debug.

**This is the main code:**

```
<div id="List">
    <div id="entries"></div>

    <input id="all" type="hidden" value="all">
    <a onclick="submitFilters('all', 'none')">
        <div id="button_all" class="buttons">
            <p>Show All</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <input id="major" type="text">
    <a onclick="submitFilters('major', 'block')">
        <div class="buttons">
            <p>Filter by Major</p>
        </div>
    </a>

    <input id="course" type="text">
    <a onclick="submitFilters('course', 'block')">
        <div class="buttons">
            <p>Filter by Course</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<script>

function submitFilters(name, buttonDisplay){
    var xmlhttp;
    var value = document.getElementById(name).value;
    alert(name + " has been clicked and value is " + value);

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        var mesgs = document.getElementById("entries");
        mesgs.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("button_all").style.display = buttonDisplay;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "queryEntries.php?show=" + name + "&value=" + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I cleaned the "href" attributes, which are not needed when use "onclick". If you want the classic link style, add this block to your HTML:

```
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using only one function to perform all the requests. It's easier to use, to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IF statment is valid in your php code. Try it like this:

if (trim($_GET['show']) === "major")

<s>Define xmlhttp using var keyword. the way you are defining it is making it global so it will always have the values of the first request after refreshing the page.</s>

***Solution 1:***
Chang this :

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

to this :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

***Solution 2:***

Use different name for it in each js function like xmlhttp1, xmlhttp2 and xmlhttp3
..........................
I recommend to use both solutions together at the same time because the query word from the input field may change so in this case solution 2 alone is not enough.

Comment: It seems he's already using `var`. But indeed if he wasn't using it, the variable would be global.

Comment: Woops, I missed that. I Edited my answer. He should then try the second solution.

Comment: Are you sure about your second solution? I mean the variable `xmlhttp` is _local_ to each function so calling one function and then the other should instanciate the variable each time.

Comment: @AnthonyB Yes, assuming that var is not used in the first place.

Comment: Ok but he's using the `var` keyword, so the variable is created/destroyed at every function call. Use different name will not make a difference in this case I think.

Comment: I'm not sure about that since different browsers behave differently especially the infamous IE aka MS Edge so always implement all possible protective measures when dealing with web apps front end.